# Issue adding order by to PIVOT group by SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot-table

The SQL Below works gr8, but the order, how to set that to put Jan, Feb, Mar order. I realize I need to do this with ordinal month but when I add in the order by I get error ***'The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.'***

The results look like :

[image]

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(TransactionDateTime))
            FROM Quotations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 
    'SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3) as [month], year(TransactionDateTime) as [year],
            isnull(count(*),0) as Total 
        FROM quotations
        group by  left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3), year(TransactionDateTime)
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS QuotationResults'



EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `TOP 100%` to the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't order a subquery unless there is a reason for the order (`TOP`, `FOR XML` etc). The reason for this is that just because you have ordered the subquery there is no reason that this order would be maintained in your outer query. SQL Server is essentially telling you that your `ORDER BY` is pointless, therefore not valid.

The solution is to simply add a column with month number to your subuquery `s`, then you can order by it. You would also need to explicitly state your select list to ensure that this new column does not appear in it:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(TransactionDateTime))
            FROM Quotations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 
    'SELECT [month], ' + @Cols + '
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3) as [month], 
            datepart(month,TransactionDateTime) as [monthNum], 
            year(TransactionDateTime) as [year],
            isnull(count(*),0) as Total 
        FROM quotations
        group by  left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3), datepart(month,TransactionDateTime), year(TransactionDateTime)
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS QuotationResults
    ORDER BY QuotationResults.MonthNum;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

The `ISNULL()` does not trap the null values because at the point of using `ISNULL()` they don't exist. `COUNT(*)` will **never** return null, so your `ISNULL()` is actually redundant.

In a very simple example if you have:

```
TransactionDateTime 
----------------------  
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-02-01
2014-03-01
```

To skip ahead one step, after your pivot you will end up with:

```
Month   2014    2015
------------------------
Jan     NULL    1
Feb     NULL    2
Mar     1       NULL
```

So you end up with NULL values, now to go back a step, if you look at the results after your aggregation you have:

```
Month   MonthNum    Year    Total
-----------------------------------
Jan     1           2015    1
Feb     2           2015    2
Mar     3           2014    1
```

So there are no rows for Jan or Feb in 2014, therefore `SUM(NULL)` will yield `NULL`. I would suggest leaving all the aggregation to the pivot function. So your non dynamic query would look something like:

```
SELECT  pvt.[Month], pvt.[2014], pvt.[2015]
FROM    (   SELECT  [Month] = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, TransactionDateTime), 3), 
                    [MonthNum] = DATEPART(MONTH, TransactionDateTime), 
                    [Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, TransactionDateTime),
                    Value = 1
            FROM    Quotations
        ) AS t
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(Value)
            FOR [year] IN ([2014], [2015])
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.MonthNum;
```

And put into dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(YEAR, TransactionDateTime))
            FROM Quotations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 
    'SELECT pvt.[Month], ' + @cols + '
    FROM    (   SELECT  [Month] = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, TransactionDateTime), 3), 
                        [MonthNum] = DATEPART(MONTH, TransactionDateTime), 
                        [Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, TransactionDateTime),
                        Value = 1
                FROM    Quotations
            ) AS t
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(Value)
                FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) AS pvt
    ORDER BY pvt.MonthNum;
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS QuotationResults
    ORDER BY QuotationResults.MonthNum;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Incredible, many thanks! Trying to figure out why the isnull() is ignore and still gives back a null. I can trap it later though, cheers, J